# 404 error, react client attempting to hit nodejs backend from nginx reverse proxy. Setup is for docker compose

Tags: reactjs, node.js, nginx, docker-compose, load-balancing

With my current setup I get a 404 error status: parsing_error in the browser console when client requests anything from backend api, this is happening at localhost:3000/login upon login attempt. I'm leaning toward the solution being in my location block in nginx.conf but at this point not sure, i've tried many different adjustments but end up with other errors. What am i missing in this setup?

**nginx.conf**

```
upstream loadbalancer {
    least_conn;
    server ws1:8081;
    server ws2:8082;
    server ws3:8083;
}


server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://loadbalancer/;
            proxy_buffering on;
        }

}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  ws1:
    image: bark-mate-be
    environment:
      - APPID=1111
      - APPPORT=8081
    networks:
      - loadbalancing
    ports:
      - "8081"
  ws2:
    image: bark-mate-be
    environment:
      - APPID=2222
      - APPPORT=8082
    ports:
      - "8082"
    networks:
      - loadbalancing
  ws3:
    image: bark-mate-be
    environment:
      - APPID=3333
      - APPPORT=8083
    ports:
      - "8083"
    networks:
      - loadbalancing
  barkmatefrontend:
    image: bark-mate-fe
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
    networks:
      - loadbalancing
    depends_on:
      - db
      - ws1
      - ws2
      - ws3
  db:
    volumes:
      - barkMate_db:/data/db
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
volumes:
  barkMate_db:
networks:
  loadbalancing:
```

**Dockerfile-client**

```
FROM node:current-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install
RUN npm ci --production
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine-slim
COPY --from=build /app/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build /app/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

**Dockerfile server**

```
FROM node:16
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the bugs, this setup is hard to test because of front end image build time. For each web server image ie (ws1,ws2...) ports were mapped incorrectly in docker-compose.yml.
For example before was

```
ws1:
image: bark-mate-be
environment:
  - APPID=1111
  - APPPORT=8081
networks:
  - loadbalancing
ports:
  - "8081"
```

now is

```
ws1:
image: bark-mate-be
environment:
  - APPID=1111
  - APPPORT=8081
networks:
  - loadbalancing
ports:
  - "8081:8080"
```

so mapping outside container port to 8081 from inside container 8080 which is exposed in the bark-mate-be image which each web server uses.
I also removed the trailing forward slash of the proxy_pass url, not sure if that made a difference but it might have thrown a misleading error in one of my prior attempts.